# Android: Push a webview in a tabview

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, tabview

I have a `TabActivity` containing an activity with a button.

When the button is pressed I wish another activity to appear in the `same tab`.

When the user presses the `back button`, the original view would appear.

Is this possible?

**Android Java or MonoDroid .NET answers are fine**

Comment: this was the solution: http://ericharlow.blogspot.ca/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implements a view extends layout and draw two views on this layout. Two views can exchange according to the actions.